# Scala stream filter behaviour

Tags: scala, stream

I'm playing with scala streams. 
Here is the stream of all integers starting from a given number.
 I have added a `println` to trace every call of from function.

```
def from(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n #:: from({ println(n); n + 1 })

val nats = from(0)         //> nats  : Stream[Int] =  Stream(0, ?)

nats.take(4).toList        //> 0
                           //| 1
                           //| 2
                           //| 3
                           //| res0: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

As expected, this is the output of my scala worksheet. Then I have created the stream of all prime numbers.

```
def sieve(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  s.head #:: sieve(s.tail.filter({ println( "---" ); _ % s.head != 0 }))
}                          //> sieve: (s: Stream[Int])Stream[Int]

val primes = sieve(from(2))//> primes  : Stream[Int] = Stream(2, ?)

primes.take(4).toList      //> 2
                           //| ---
                           //| 3
                           //| 4
                           //| ---
                           //| 5
                           //| 6
                           //| ---
                           //| res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 5, 7)
```

Here comes the question. I have made what in my opinion should be a little change, adding the `x` parameter instead of `_` placeholder. Surprisingly the output is quite different:

```
def sieve(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  s.head #:: sieve(s.tail.filter(x => { println("---"); (x % s.head) != 0 }))
}                          //> sieve: (s: Stream[Int])Stream[Int]

val primes = sieve(from(2))//> primes  : Stream[Int] = Stream(2, ?)

primes.take(4).toList      //> 2
                           //| ---
                           //| 3
                           //| ---
                           //| 4
                           //| ---
                           //| ---
                           //| 5
                           //| ---
                           //| 6
                           //| ---
                           //| ---
                           //| ---
                           //| res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 5, 7)
```

I don't understand why all these repetitions. 
What's wrong in using the explicit parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is because `{ println( "---" ); _ % s.head != 0 }` is short for `{ println( "---" ); x => x % s.head != 0 }` rather than `{ x => println( "---" ); x % s.head != 0 }`.

In the first case you first call `println` and then return the function, so `---` is printed once per `filter` call; in the second it's once per `filter` call per element of the stream being filtered (and because `sieve` is recursive and filters the stream again, you end up with multiple `---` for each element of the output).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got what's the difference. It is not clear only why the returned function have to filter more times the same number.

Comment: You can see it better if you write `{ x => println( s"${s.head} --- $x" ); x % s.head != 0 }` (and similarly for the other option. Then you'll see for each printed line which `filter` it refers to.

Comment: "... it is not clear only why the returned function have to filter more times ..." it is not because it is the returned function, but because the filter is applied on the collection items using an anonymous function in parameter. The anonymous function (x => ...) does not include the println when you used _.

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare the argument to sieve in both cases, have a close look:

```
s.tail.filter(     { println( "---" );       _ % s.head  != 0  })
s.tail.filter(x => { println( "--- " + x ); (x % s.head) != 0 })
```

Do you see the difference in the println calls?

Now the outputs

```
First:         Second:
//> 2          //> 2
//| ---        //| --- 3
```

The crucial difference:

```
println( "---"      )
println( "--- " + x )
```

In the 2nd case you are appending `" "+x` right after the dashes and that's the exact difference between the cases.

Comment: @pedrofurla, count the number of output lines.

Comment: @pedrofurla I have updated the question to better explain the problem.